# firebase set failed first argument contains undefined in property

Tags: json, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, redux

When I create an event, I do this:

```
export const eventCreate = ({ title, time, location }) => {
  const newPostKey = firebase.database().ref('/events').push().key;
  const update = {};

  const postDetails = {
    eventId: newPostKey,
    title,
    ...
    goingNumber: 1,
    ...
  };

  update[`/events/${newPostKey}`] = postDetails;

  return (dispatch) => {
    firebase.database().ref()
      .update(update)
      .then(() => {
        dispatch({ type: EVENT_CREATE });
      })
      .then(() => newPostKey);
  };
};
```

in the database:

[image]

later when I try to update the `goingNumber`:

```
export const eventSave = ({ goingNumber, eventId }) => {    
  return (dispatch) => {
    firebase.database().ref(`/events/${eventId}`)
      .set({ goingNumber })
      .then(() => {
        dispatch({ type: EVENT_SAVE_SUCCESS });
      });
  };
};
```

I get this error saying:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not passing in a value for `goingNumber`. My guess is that you're looking for

```
firebase.database().ref(`/events/${eventId}`)
        .child('goingNumber').set(goingNumber )
```